# Пересечение роутов react и nodejs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, react-router-dom

Приложение на react и express. В реакте роуты реализованы через react-router-dom, в ноде через express router.

Express отдает статику: app.use(express.static('app')) - В папку app закидывается билд реакта

Проблема в том, что переходя по адресу http://localhost:8080/ я попадаю на главную страницу приложения, на которой есть ссылки на другие страницы через react-router-dom, допустим, я перехожу по одной из них и попадаю на http://localhost:8080/employee при перезагрузке страницы я получаю ошибку Cannot GET /employees - как будто я делаю запрос в свой апи, а не использую роутинг реакта, тоже самое, если я просто попытаюсь перейти на страницу по ссылке, при этом обычные роуты ноды работают. Получается так, что по роутам реакта я могу передвигаться только с главной страницы

Что можно сделать в таком случае? Может быть нужно как то разделить апи и фронт? Или я не так отдаю статику? Будут полезны ссылки на правильную реализацию отдачи статики в связке express - react, nginx пока не использую - хочу знать как это реализовать на express

Comment: Примитивно можно реализовать так... Все что начинается на `\api` - обрабатывает АПИ и дает 404 если такого роутинга в АПИ нет. А все остальное считать "статикой Реакта".

Comment: Вот статейка про примитивный сервер на `Node.js` для `React.js` - https://metanit.com/web/react/1.6.php

Comment: Я читал эту статью, что-то уж там совсем примитивно, да и роутинга на фронте нет

Comment: Да и не совсем представляю, как реализовать даже ваш примитивный вариант, если у меня вообще все роуты обрабатывает нода, то есть до роутинга реакта там дело даже не доходит или есть способ редиректа на роутинг реакта, если нода отдает 404?

Comment: Вот статейка уже с express - https://www.bezkoder.com/integrate-react-express-same-server-port/

Comment: Только там нужно вот это `app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});` отправлять на все, что не "backend"...

Comment: Вот статейка по 404 - https://digitrain.ru/articles/377477/

Comment: Огромное спасибо, кажется это именно то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'view/home', 'index.html'))
})
app.get('/other-app*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'view/other-app', 'index.html'))
})
```

Если нужно к примеру запустить 2 React приложения на разных роутах